# CrowdTangle API syntax?

Tags: api

Super new to this sort of thing so please bear with me, I'm sure this is a facepalm-worthy question to anyone who knows anything about using APIs. I'm trying to use the CrowdTangle API (just got access) but their [documentation](https://github.com/CrowdTangle/API/wiki) isn't really helpful (at least to me). Even though it lists a bunch of parameters you can use, it doesn't give syntax examples so I'm not sure how to implement the parameters. For example, I tried to test a simple search for "dog" by doing https://api.crowdtangle.com/posts/search=dog?token=[my-token] and I got this error message:
{"status":400,"message":"Required String parameter 'searchTerm' is not present"}.

Does anyone know what the general syntax would be for this and how you use the parameters? I'm obviously looking to do more complicated searches than "dog", but I think if someone can just breakdown what the general syntax is I can probably manage from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
https://api.crowdtangle.com/posts?token=your-api-token
```

just to get the ball rolling. Looks good? Then try:

```
https://api.crowdtangle.com/posts/search?token=MYTOKEN&searchTerm=waffles
```

And you should be good to go. You'll get a 401 if your token is valid but not good for that usage type.